# Two fields in jQuery-ui autocomplete dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, underscore.js, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an object that goes like this:

```
[{
  "suburbName": "ABBOTSBURY",
  "postCode": "2176",
  "state": "NSW",
  "country": "AU"
}, {
  "suburbName": "ABBOTSFORD",
  "postCode": "2046",
  "state": "NSW",
  "country": "AU"
}, {
  "suburbName": "ACACIA GARDENS",
  "postCode": "2763",
  "state": "NSW",
  "country": "AU"
}/*, etc */]
```

Where there may be some suburbs with the same suburbName but different postCodes and states.

I'd like to stick the suburbName and postcode together somehow in the autocomplete dropdown, either by just creating a new array with a string containing suburb and postcode or by using some special function for the source.

What do you think is the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 2):

[`source`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) expects an array, so you can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
$(myElement).autocomplete({
    source: dataArray.map(function(val) {
        return val.suburbName + " " + val.postCode;
    })
});
```